# Converting Do expression to ParallelDo

Tags: matrix, parallelization

I'm trying to use `ParallelDo` to speed up my code, but a problem confused me. In the following code I use `Do` and get the expected results. It constructs a correct matrix `CC` that I want:

```
CC = Range[Nmax];
Do[
  A = 
    I/3.5 (n - m)!/(n + m)! SphericalHankelH2[n, 0.01] SphericalBesselJ[n, 0.016] 
      LegendreP[n, m, Cos[π/4]];
  B = 
    1/(I 0.036) (n - m)!/(n + m)! SphericalHankelH2[n, 0.01] 
      (D[SphericalBesselJ[n, x], x] /. x -> 0.05) LegendreP[n, m, Cos[π/4]];
  Kn[t_, p_] = 
   mSum[
     (A Sin[t] D[LegendreP[n, m, Cos[t]], {t, 2}] + 
       (A + B) Cos[t] D[LegendreP[n, m, Cos[t]], t] + 
       (A - B) Sin[t] LegendreP[n, m, Cos[t]]) 
     Cos[m (p - π/2)], 
   {m, -n, n}];
  CC[[n]] = 
    Integrate[
      (Kn[t, p] (SphericalHarmonicY[1, 0, t, p])\[Conjugate] Sin[t]), 
      {t, 0, π}, {p, 0, 2 π}], 
  {n, 1, Nmax}];

CC // MatrixForm
```

But when I substitute `ParallelDo` for `Do`, the matrix `CC` doesn't fill. 
What should I do in `ParallelDo` to achieve the right result, the same as I get when using `Do`?

Comment: Rather than constructing an array and then changing its elements in a loop, in *Mathematica* it is more natural to use `Table` to construct the array directly from the elements you want. Then, `ParallelTable` is the natural speedup.

Comment: What is `mSum`?

Comment: Sum is correct, not mSum